# Convert CMSampleBufferRef to video

Tags: stream, nsstream

(Sorry for my english)

How to convert/encode CMSampleBufferRef to video to send using NSOutputStream?

I need stream video from my ipad to local network, i use a AVFoundation framework to get a video. Now, i need convert this video to the right format to send to Http Server using NSOutputStream.

if i´m doing something wrong, please tell me

Regards.

Comment: Did you find any solution ? I can send images over network and show them on other device but how to send audio ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this helps you, but take a look on my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10056460/ios-receiving-video-from-network).

I written a program where I get audio and video from "master" device and send on the fly to a "slave" device.

The approach works but I need to optimize the transmission to improve experience and makes the app more like a "facetime".